# How to use spoon to get the properties of a class in java?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, inria-spoon

I have a java file and I want to get the exception message for the exception type after the throw keyword

```java
 // this is the code of D:\\ProjectFile\\AST\\Test\\000001\\test.java
 if (len < 0 || offset < 0 || len + offset > b.length) {
            String str = "index out of bounds";
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(s);
        }
```

For example, I want to get the string, "index out of bounds" inthe "D:\ProjectFile\AST\Test\000001\test.java", because he is a property of IndexOutOfBoundsException

So, When I use [spoon](https://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/), I don't find enough examples to teach me

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Launcher launcher = new Launcher();

    launcher.addInputResource("D:\\ProjectFile\\AST\\Test\\000001\\test.java");

    launcher.buildModel();
    CtModel model = launcher.getModel();


    List<CtThrow> throwList = model.getElements(new TypeFilter<>(CtThrow.class));

    for (int i = 0; i < throwList.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(throwList.get(i).getThrownExpression());
    }
}
```

Using the code above, I can only get the following：

```
new java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException(s)
```

I can not get the value of `s`.

**I want to be able to check the constructor of this exception type and get its property value, how should I do this?**

Answer (score 0):

try it  :

```
 IndexOutOfBoundsException e  = new java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException(s);
        Field[] field = e.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<field.length ; i++)
            java.lang.System.out.print(field[i].get(e));
```

> But it won't be able to get the value declared as private

Comment: thanks so much, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Error message says `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is private static.   I want to parse a java file by spoon and get the exception message in the java file, it doesn't seem to fit my scenario?

Comment: ok bro , it not work private field

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of [data-flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis) for this.

In Spoon, this is not in spoon-core but in submodule https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/tree/master/spoon-dataflow